# Conditional gsub replacement

Tags: r

I have text data (in R) and want to replace some characters with other characters in a data frame.  I thought this would be an easy task using strsplit on spaces and create a vector that can I can then use matching (%in%) which can then be pasted back together.  But then I thought about punctuation.  There's no space between the last word of a sentence and the punctuation at the end.

I figure there's probably a more simple way to achieve what I want than the convoluted mess that's becoming my code.  I would appreciate direction with this problem.

```
#Character String
x <- "I like 346 ice cream cones.  They're 99 percent good!  I ate 46."

#Replacement Values Dataframe
  symbol text                     
1 "346"  "three hundred forty six"
2 "99"   "ninety nine"            
3 "46"   "forty six" 

#replacement dataframe
numDF <- 
data.frame(symbol = c("346","99", "46"),
           text = c("three hundred forty six", "ninety nine","forty six"),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
[1] "I like three hundred forty six ice cream cones.  They're ninety nine percent good!  You ate forty six?")
```

*EDIT:  I originally entitled this conditional gsub because that what it seems like to me even though there is no gsub involved.*

Comment: Your `dput`'ed data.frame didn't evaluate to a data.frame. I just edited your post so that it now does.  Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Sorry about that Josh.  Thanks for taking care of that and for your response.  I didn't know about the gsubfn package.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this, inspired by Josh O'Brien's answer, does it:

```
x <- "I like 346 ice cream cones.  They're 99 percent good!  I ate 46."
numDF <- structure(c("346", "99", "46", "three hundred forty six", "ninety nine", 
"forty six"), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", 
"3"), c("symbol", "text")))

pat <-  paste(numDF[,"symbol"], collapse="|")
repeat {
    m <- regexpr(pat, x)
    if(m==-1) break
    sym <- regmatches(x,m)
    regmatches(x,m) <- numDF[match(sym, numDF[,"symbol"]), "text"]
}
x
```

Comment: Beautiful  All three answers work but yours is the most straight forward while staying in base.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses `gsubfn` in the package of the same name:

```
library(gsubfn)

(pat <-  paste(numDF$symbol, collapse="|"))
# [1] "346|99|46"

gsubfn(pattern = pat,
       replacement = function(x) {
           numDF$text[match(x, numDF$symbol)]
       },
       x)
[1] "I like three hundred forty six ice cream cones.  They're ninety nine percent good!  I ate forty six."
```

Comment: Josh I like it and didn't specify this but this is for a package and I am trying not rely on anything except base functions. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can split on whitespace or word boundaries (which will match between a word and punctuation):

```
> x
[1] "I like 346 ice cream cones.  They're 99 percent good!  I ate 46."
> strsplit(x, split='\\s|\\>|\\<')
[[1]]
 [1] "I"       "like"    "346"     "ice"     "cream"   "cones"   "."      
 [8] ""        "They"    "'re"     "99"      "percent" "good"    "!"      
[15] ""        "I"       "ate"     "46"      "."
```

Then you can do your replacements.

Comment: I made it work with your answer but Karsten W.'s answer was just a bit neater and faster. Thanks for the help.  +1

Comment: I like this, but it seems like it'd be tricky to paste the processed result back together, with spaces between some strings but not others.  And if there is *sometimes* a space between a word and sentence-terminating punctuation, you'd definitely lose that: `x <- "word. word .";  strsplit(x, split='\\s|\\>|\\<')[[1]]`.

Comment: @Josh O'Brien it worked for me by using gsub and searching for the following punctuation (' ? . !) and a leading space and subbing it out for just that punctuation minus the space.  This took 4 more lines of code (I am sure there was a faster way) but it does indeed work.

Comment: @TylerRinker -- Sure. And the case that I pasted in at the end of my comment is *probably* an irrelevant edge case, as not many sentences will end with a space and then a punctuation mark.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `Reduce` from `base`.

```
list_df <- apply(numDF, 1, as.list)
Reduce(function(x, l) gsub(l$symbol, l$text, x), list_df, init = x)
```

EDIT. Here is the complete solution utilizing the `numbers2words` function directly..

```
list_df <- as.numeric(regmatches(x, gregexpr('[0-9]+', x))[[1]])
Reduce(function(x, l) gsub(l, numbers2words(l), x), list_df, init = x)
```

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't exactly clear whether you really wanted to convert digits to their alpha equivalents. If so then here is a much more general strategy. There are (at least) two numeric to text conversion functions in the rhelp archives: Jim Lemon's `digits2text` and John Fox's `numberstowords`. I also switched over to `gregexpr` to get to a vectorized approach:

Cutting and pasting [Lemon's function from the HTML found here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/Rhelp10/2008-March/156081.html) worked out of the box:

```
>     m <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", x)
>     sym <- regmatches(x,m)
>     regmatches(x,m) <- digits2text(as.numeric(sym[[1]]))
illion = 0 
digilen = 3 
digitext = three hundred forty six 
[1] 6 4 3
> 
> x
[1] "I like three hundred forty six ice cream cones.  They're three hundred forty six percent good!  I ate three hundred forty six."
```

I needed to do some editing of the numberstowords because there were some missing linefeeds that messed up the parsing (and I include the successful version below this demonstration:

```
>     m <- gregexpr("[0-9]+", x)
>     sym <- regmatches(x,m)
>     regmatches(x,m) <- numbers2words(as.numeric(sym[[1]]))
> 
> x
[1] "I like three hundred forty six ice cream cones.  They're three hundred forty six percent good!  I ate three hundred forty six."
```

Fox's function edited from: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/2715.html

```
numbers2words <- function(x){

    helper <- function(x){

        digits <- rev(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]])
        nDigits <- length(digits)
        if (nDigits == 1) as.vector(ones[digits])
        else if (nDigits == 2)
            if (x <= 19) as.vector(teens[digits[1]])
                else trim(paste(tens[digits[2]], 
                           Recall(as.numeric(digits[1]))))
        else if (nDigits == 3) trim(paste(ones[digits[3]], "hundred", 
            Recall(makeNumber(digits[2:1]))))
        else {
            nSuffix <- ((nDigits + 2) %/% 3) - 1
            if (nSuffix > length(suffixes)) stop(paste(x, "is too large!"))
            trim(paste(Recall(makeNumber(digits[
                nDigits:(3*nSuffix + 1)])),
                suffixes[nSuffix],  
                Recall(makeNumber(digits[(3*nSuffix):1]))))
            }
        }
    trim <- function(text){
        gsub("^\ ", "", gsub("\ *$", "", text))
        }      


    makeNumber <- function(...) as.numeric(paste(..., collapse=""))
     opts <- options(scipen=100)
    on.exit(options(opts))
    ones <- c("", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",

        "eight", "nine")
    names(ones) <- 0:9
    teens <- c("ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen",

        "sixteen", " seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen")
     names(teens) <- 0:9
    tens <- c("twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty",
                 "seventy", "eighty", "ninety")
    names(tens) <- 2:9
    x <- round(x)
    suffixes <- c("thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion")
     if (length(x) > 1) return(sapply(x, helper))
     helper(x)
    }
```

Comment: DWin you are correct in that I wanted to take text and sub out the numbers for text.  I originally posted this question on talkstats.com http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/22564-Replacement-in-gsub-as-a-function-argument and found the Fox function.  I got some help from bryangoodrich there but was at an impasse in the process in subbing the numeric to text replacements back into the original text.  This question was more specifically in dealing with that piece of the puzzle. Thank you for your help.+1

Comment: Plus my question about replacing numeric values with their word equivalents I posted on talkstats was more specific to me.  The question about conditional gsubbing is much more generalized to lots of people not just people dealing with numeric values.  I may use a similar approach in an abbreviation replacement function I need to compile.

Comment: I noticed that my replacements were not cycling through the numeric values properly.