# str_replace character vector with multiple pattern and multiple repleacements

Tags: regex, r, stringr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional gsub replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703398/conditional-gsub-replacement)

How can I replace certian elements of a character vector with defined replacements?

```
county <- c("wagner", "mccain", "mcclain", "dallas")

pattern     <- c("mccain",  "mcclain",   "mcdonald")
replacement <- c("mc cain", "mc clain",  "mc donald")

library(stringr)
str_replace(county, pattern, replacement)
```

Seems like this should be simple but I have been messing with it for a long time and cant figure it out.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make your examples *fully* reproducible, especially when using non-standard packages, by loading any packages needed to make it reproducible.

Comment: Is `"mclain"` a typo? Should it be `"mcclain"`?

Comment: If you feel like downloading my beta package `qdap` it does this easily.  To download: `install.packages("devtools"); library(devtools); install_github("qdap", "trinker")`, to do what you want: `library(qdap); mgsub(pattern, replacement, county)`.  I tried it on your sample and it worked perfectly (though look at Luciano's comment).

Comment: @Tyler Rinker- qdap install failed: * building 'qdap_0.1.0.tar.gz'
 ERROR
packaging into .tar.gz failed
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:

Comment: @Galvin Simpson - my apploogies..please find edited question

Comment: If your problem is specific to "mc" names, consider doing something `gsub("^mc(\\B)", "mc \\1", county)`. But then maybe you just used that as an example...

Comment: What I showed in my question was just an example and in the larger vector there is other "mc" names that I did not want to replace, so for the replacement I thought it prodent to be explicit with both what I wanted to replace and the replacement.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Mike sorry about that.  I know there have been some issue for mac users downloading `qdap` because of the java issues in `openNLP` (I import this package).  Maybe you need the build tools (what ever system you're on).  See: https://github.com/trinker/qdap for more help on that but this may be more of a pain on you rump than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you don't want to use regular expressions to do a search-and-replace (via `gsub` for example). In that matter, the use of the variable name `pattern` may have been misleading.

Instead, you just want to do a plain substitution where you have an exact match. You need to use `match` and `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(is.na(idx <- match(county, pattern)), county, replacement[idx])
# [1] "wagner"   "mc cain"  "mc clain" "dallas"
```

You can also put that in a function:

```
substitute.all <- function(pattern, replacement, x) {
   idx <- match(x, pattern)
   return(ifelse(is.na(idx), x, replacement[idx]))
}
substitute.all(pattern, replacement, county)
# [1] "wagner"   "mc cain"  "mc clain" "dallas"
```