# R Pattern Replace: nfa has too many states

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame with large amounts of text in each observation and want to replace specific word groups by combining them into one word. This is an example of the code I have been trying that I found here: [Conditional gsub replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703398/conditional-gsub-replacement)

```
text = "this is a test this is another test test this is another test this is"
replace <- data.frame(symbol = c("this is", "test"), text=c("thisis", "yes"))
pat <-  paste(replace[,"symbol"], collapse="|")
repeat {
    m <- regexpr(pat, text)
    if(m==-1) break
    sym <- regmatches(text,m)
    regmatches(text,m) <- replace[match(sym, replace[,"symbol"]), "text"]
}
text
```

However, the "replace" data frame has 7614 replacement values and I am getting

> "Error in regexpr(pat, text) :    assertion 'tree->num_tags ==
>   num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file
>   '../../../../../R-3.3.0/src/extra/tre/tre-compile.c', line 634"

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to reduce the number of OR statements in your regex "(this|that|the other)", and call different groups multiple times: "(this|that)" then "the other".

Comment: I think that could be one solution, but I am unsure of exactly how many or statements I can use. I split the replace in half and got the same error.

Comment: I think you’ve simply hit a hard-coded limit in the regex engine (well, the error message more or less states this outright). Since you’re essentially matching fixed strings, there are other algorithms you could try, e.g. [Aho–Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [Wu–Manber](http://webglimpse.net/pubs/TR94-17.pdf) — unfortunately you may have to implement these yourself first (on the plus side, Wu–Manber is easy to implement, it’s essentially a parallelised Horspool).